# no suitable user-defined conversion C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am making a simple pricer on C++ but I got stuck with a conversion type error.

In brief, I have a class `Option` which has the method `PricingByCRR(BinomialModel Model)` where `BinomialModel` is another class. I inherit publically the class Call from the class Option in the following way:

```
class Option
{
public:
    virtual double Payoff(double s)=0;
    double PricingByCRR(BinomialModel Model);
private:
    int N;
};

class Call: public Option
{
public:
    void SetK(double K_);
    double Payoff(double s);
private:
    double K;
};
```

Here comes my problem: in my main I create a `CallOption` which is a call but I am not able to apply the method `PricingByCRR` even though it is supposed to be inherited by the class Option...

```
int main()
{
    BinomialModel Model;

    if (Model.InputData()==1) return 1;

    Call CallOption;
    CallOption.InputData();
    cout << "European call option price = "<< CallOption.PricingByCRR(Model) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message I get is

> no suitable user-defined conversion from 'BinomialModel' to
>   'BinomialModel'.

This is my BinomialModel:

```
class BinomialModel
{
public:
    double PricingProbability();    // Risk neutral probability; well-known formula
    double S(int n, int i);         // This function computes the stock price at node n, i
    int InputData();                // Entering data
    double GetR();

private:
    double S0;  // Initial value for the stock
    double u;   // The stock's price is u*S0
    double d;   // The stock's price is d*S0
    double r;   // Interest rate
};
```

It must be a virtuality problem but I am not able to resolve it. Anyone has an idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should post all the code, including the #includes. I don't see any inheritance problem with your code, it seems more an include, namespaces problem.

Comment: **–1** This is **not the real code**. There is a problem with `CallOption.InputData()`, but there's nothing that could give the alleged error.

Comment: `CallOption.InputData()` has nothing to do I am afraid. I got a problem with Model on the next line. If I omit `CallOption.InputData()` the problem is still there...

Comment: voted to close as lacking example

Comment: thank you for your extreeeeeeeeeeemly useful comment. I managed to solve my problem which was obviously the fact that I didn't insert `#ifndef` and `#endif` in the beginning and in the end of my class (which you could've noticed, right...?)